# Resetting an array and filling it with values in a bash script

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

I wanted to know the "right" way to do this. Basically, I have a list of files that are in an array called `current`. This is declared as a global variable that looks like this: `current=()`. I have successfully put all the files in this array. But now, I am going through and parsing arguments to filter out these files and directories.

For example, to implement the `-name '*.pattern'` command, I pass in the `pattern` to `process_name()` which does this:

```
process_name ()
{
    local new_cur=()
    for i in "${current[@]}"; do
        if [[ "$i" == "$1" ]]; then
            new_cur+=("$i")
        fi
    done
    current=( "${new_cur[@]}" )
}
```

After the loop finishes I want to "clear" my `current` array. Then I want to loop over the `new_cur` array, and basically make it equal to `current`, or if I can, just do something like `$current = $new_cur` (although I know this won't work).

I've tried doing this after the for loop (in `process_name()`), but my array `current` doesn't actually change:

```
current=( "${new_cur[@]}" )
```

Is there a good way to do this? Or a right way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply clone an array using `array1=( "${array2[@]}" )`. For example:

```
[STEP 100] $ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.3.33(1)-release
[STEP 101] $ cat foo.sh
current=(aa bb cc)

process_name ()
{
    local new_cur=()

    for i in "${current[@]}"; do
        if [[ "$i" == "$1" ]]; then
            new_cur+=("$i")
        fi
    done
    current=( "${new_cur[@]}" )
}

process_name aa

for i in "${current[@]}"; do
    printf '%s\n' "$i"
done
[STEP 102] $ bash foo.sh
aa
[STEP 103] $
```

Comment: Will this overwrite all the values at current?

Comment: Yes, the old array will be overwritten.

Comment: I did some testing and even though my local variable has the correct values... after resetting the array with the solution you provided, `current` ends up empty, basically, `cur_new` never gets written into it. I'm doing `current=( "${cur_new[@]}" )`

Comment: It does not work for you? Can you post your new code?

Comment: Just updated it.. I realized I didn't need to check for the types yet. And printing out `new_cur` in the loop yields correct results. However, once out of the function, printing out `current` doing `for i in "${current[@]}"; do .. printf '%s\n' "$i" .. done` does not work :(

Comment: After `current=( "${new_cur[@]}" )` please add one line `declare -p current` to see if `current` has expected values in it.

Comment: It outputs `declare -a current='()'`

Comment: There must be something wrong. Try `bash -x /your/script.sh`.

Comment: Updated my answer based on your code. See if it works.

Comment: Your script does work on it's own, but attempts to implement it in mine are failing :( I have my script here, with the usage: http://pastebin.com/YmVjPMBj Thank you for all of the help!

Comment: Then you better ask a new question since the array assignment problem has been solved.

Comment: Will do! Thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 15):

To reset an array just use:

```
current=()
```

This will delete old entries and declare a 0 element array.

Comment: How would I load the values from `new_cur` into `current` after resetting them?

Comment: You already had `for` loop to load values from array1 to array2.